# "Join community" popup strings need to be added to Transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, login, localization, transifex

On [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), I clicked on the "Follow Post" button on a question, but I did not have an account there.  The popup that contained the "Join" button was mostly English, not Russian; only the community name and Join Community text was in Russian:

[image]

I noticed this also when I joined [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), and it happened when I joined [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/):

[image]

Can we please add these strings to Transifex?  It seems a little counterintuitive to have the "Join Community" strings in English on a site made specifically for another language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strings are in there, I just checked. If you go into the traducir site, search for "Join the" and you will see a string "Join the $siteName$ community" come up for translation.